# cannot cast from view to mapview

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

import part

```
package com.example.mapsearch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ZoomControls;
import java.util.List;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
```

Among the following - mv=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mv);

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MapView mv;
MapController controller;
Bitmap bmpArrow;
RadioButton rbNormal;
RadioButton rbSatellite;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bmpArrow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (
            getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mv=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mv);
```

errors -
cannot cast from view to mapview &
line breakpoint:MainActivity[line:__] -onCreate(Bundle)

How can i fix them? Thank you

Comment: this is normally deriving from some errors in your layout.xml.  are there any warnings?

Comment: Some yellow warning, but no red error .
(EditText& TextView)

Comment: Check your `XML` file, you need to have id mv assigned for `MapView` widget.

Comment: Best to paste your XML layout as well to see if theres any errors in there.

Comment: res/layout/activity_main.xml? no red error...

Comment: "no red error" doesn't mean that your xml is correct neither. Post it or get no help. pretty easy :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it cannot cast to a map view it is because whatever you are trying to cast is not actually a map view.

We need code, look at other questions and try and edit your question to include code, your layout file, so forth.